# Asmack login issue on Android 5.0 and above

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am facing an asmack SSL connection issue on Android 5.0 and above. I think it's related to security.

I resolved it by disabling following before connecting:

```
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
```

But I do want security enabled. How to resolve it without disabling  `setSecurityMode`?

I looked the changes 5.0 
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#ssl

But can't find the solution

my logcat is

```
02-26 17:28:20.596: W/System.err(23043):   -- caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
02-26 17:28:20.596: W/System.err(23043): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
02-26 17:28:20.596: W/System.err(23043):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:392)
02-26 17:28:20.601: W/System.err(23043):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:652)
02-26 17:28:20.601: W/System.err(23043):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:614)
02-26 17:28:20.601: W/System.err(23043): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x9fca9e00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
02-26 17:28:20.601: W/System.err(23043): error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:765 0xaec30bf9:0x00000000)
02-26 17:28:20.601: W/System.err(23043):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
02-26 17:28:20.601: W/System.err(23043):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:320)
```

Comment: Could you include the error message you get when security is enabled and you experience this issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it I have added logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
        config.setTruststorePassword(null);
        config.setTruststorePath(null);
    } else {
        config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
        String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        if (path == null)
            path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator
                    + "etc" + File.separator + "security"
                    + File.separator + "cacerts.bks";
        config.setTruststorePath(path);
    }
```

With this I was using self signed ssl certificate. It should be resolved by adding ssl certificate on openfire and using it in the app

cvofjaspreet@gmail.com

Comment: Can any buddy explain how to add ssl certificate on openfire ?